# How to accept JSON pojo representation and a path param in jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, put

I'm working on REST web-service where in one PUT request i have to accept two things :

1. `String id;`
2. `JSON` representation of `POJO` (Basically a POJO).

I can have a **@PathParam** for **'id'** but what should i use for **'second'** parameter (POJO)?.

How can i write my method for **PUT** request:

```
@PUT
public String doSomething(// What will go here?)
{
  // code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
@Accepts("application/json")
public Response putPojo(@PathParam("id") String id, Pojo pojo) {
  return Response.ok().build();
}
```

If the `Pojo` class has JAXB annotations, JAX-RS will map the incoming JSON to a `POJO` instance.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Pojo {
  @XmlElement
  String id;

  // Getter, Setter, ...
}
```